# How will an RSVP form stay on the same section after submitting on a one page WordPress layout

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a one page layout WordPress page and an RSVP form at the bottom and The RSVP form works just fine.

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I try to submit the name of the guest, the page loads and you will brought now at the topmost section of the page instead of the bottom part where you will continue to fill up the RSVP form. The RSVP form has two parts, first the name of the guest and second, the actual selection of the RSVP options. So after submitting, you will need to scroll down at the bottom of the page just to see if you entered your name correctly or if your RSVP has been completed.

This RSVP form is a plugin from WordPress: RSVP plugin

I just want to use this RSVP form to work on a one page layout.

**SOME SOLUTIONS THAT I'M THINKING:**

1. *AJAX* - I think using AJAX will do the trick but I really don't know how to put AJAX into the plugin and into my WordPress page. I tried installing AJAX plugins but I'm not sure how to work it out.
2. *ANCHOR* TAG - I think if there is an anchor tag at the end of the URL, the page will force the browser to stay at the bottom of the page where the RSVP section is located. But this anchor tag should be automatically be there when you scroll on every section of the one page layout. But how will I do that?

I also tried malsup's [Jquery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) but I really don't know how to work on it. Whenever I submit the form, an alert pops out.

Comment: Both of your solutions look good but you will probably need to modify the RSVP plugin to support those.

Comment: Hi @gaborlenard, Say I can edit the RSVP plugin, would you know any workaround on it?